# Return programs to window size after docking / undocking macbook pro?

Tags: macos, mac, laptop, multiple-monitors, docking-station

I have a 13 inch macbook pro that I'm using with a Henge Docks vertical docking station and two external monitors. I switch back and forth between the dock and using the laptop by itself. When I plug my computer back in to the dock, the programs obviously don't go back to their original sizes on my external screens. In fact they don't even return to the original monitor that they were on when the machine was docked previously.

This creates a problem as every time I plug back into the dock, I have to re-adjust the window sizes for each application, and then if I have to undock again, I know I'll have to resize all the windows when I dock again.

Is there any software, or are there any options on the mac, that will set the windows back to where they were automatically every time I dock my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a pretty cheap solution to this problem namely, some software called "[Display Maid](http://www.funk-isoft.com/display-maid.html)" that will allow users to save their window locations, and it automatically detects when you are connected to your external monitors and rearranges your windows to fit the monitors, or according to another layout / arrangement that you have saved. It's not free but it is only $5 in the app store.

Comment: If anyone else comes up with a cheaper or free way to do the same thing, then I will select that as the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful app called [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/) that I've been using for years.  Every display configuration can have a separate set of window settings.  I use my MBP15 standalone, connected to a Thunderbolt Display and via two 20" displays merged using Matrox DualHead2Go and it's worked flawlessly.  It's $15 and well worth it.